# Composite ID in Hibernate how to map Key class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How to implements a composite key, let’s make a really easy example users attending events, three database tables: User, Event, Users_Attending_Events this last table has three colums: userID, eventID; which are joined with the respective ID of the other two table and success, which determines if a User showed off to an Event.

I want Attending to be a separate class and don't make a direct join on User and Event beacuse Attending contains the "success" information, and it has to be separately managed.

My implementation

User object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[users]")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userID;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attend", targetEntity = Attending.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Attending> attendEvents = new HashSet<Attending>();
...
// setters, getters, constructors, equal and hash ...
}
```

Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer eventID;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attend", targetEntity = Attending.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Attending> participants = new HashSet<Attending>();
...
// setters, getters, constructors, equal and hash ...
}
```

Attending class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_attending_events")
public class Attending implements Serializable {

        @EmbeddedId
        protected AttendingID attend;

        private Integer success;
    ...
    // setters, getters, constructors, equal and hash ...
    }
```

AttendingID class, for composite key:

```
  @Embeddable
  public class AttendingID implements Serializable {

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "users_userID", referencedColumnName = "userID")
        private Integer user;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Event.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "events_eventID", referencedColumnName = "eventID")
        private Integer event;
    ...
    // setters, getters, constructors, equal and hash ...
    }
```

While Running I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKlerh9fv4q1rjiusg0ful3m15j:users_attending_events [events_eventID,users_userID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (users [userID])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The Exception is quite straightforward saying that the mapped Foreign keys are not of expected type, and your problem is that you are trying to map the `@ManyToOne` relationship in an attribute of type `Integer` which is the wrong part here.

**Solution:**

The `@ManyToOne` annotation should reference the mapping `Entity` in your case `User` and `Event` and not a primitive type or a primary key of the Entity.

But to define  the `Embeddable` Primary key you have two options here:

1. Use just the Mapped entities primary keys as attribute in your `Embeddable` class.

Your code will be:

```
@Embeddable
public class AttendingID implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "users_userID")
    private Integer userID;

    @Column(name = "events_eventID")
    private Integer eventID;

    ...
    // setters, getters, constructors, equal and hash ...
}
```

2. Or use the two Mapped entities as attributes in your Embeddable Primary key and reference them with a `@ManyToOne` annotation.

So in your code you will just need to change the types of the `user` and

```
@Embeddable
public class AttendingID implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_userID", referencedColumnName = "userID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Event.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "events_eventID", referencedColumnName = "eventID")
    private Event event;

    ...
    // setters, getters, constructors, equal and hash ...
}
```

**Documentation:**

For further reading and more options you can check the [**5.1.2.1. Composite identifier** Section in Hibernate Mapping Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e4819) it shows and explains clearly all possible cases to Map a composite primary key.

---

### Edit:

After re-reading your question, focusing better in the problem and thinking about it from a design point of vue, *I think your situation would be better illustrated with* **a `ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Event` entities with a Join  Table `Attending` having an Extra column `success`**, it will handle better your situation and resolve the problem.

I suggest you to take a look at this [**Hibernate Many-to-Many Association with Extra Columns in Join Table Example** tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example) it shows a similar `ManyToMany` solution.

Comment: Thanks man, I corrected my code, firstly using your option 1 and I get exactly the same exception; then I tried with the option 2 and I still get the same exception, what I noticed is that the reference in User or Event: 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attend", targetEntity = Attending.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Attending> attendEvents = new HashSet<Attending>();

is the key mappedBy =”attend” wrong at this place?

Comment: @mattobob In the `mappedBy` we use the name of the attribute in the other side of the mapping so it should be `mappedBy="user"` and  `mappedBy="event"` respectively.

Comment: Corrected now I get Exception: AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: model.Attending.user in model.User.attendEvents; Attending.user is not defined but AttendingID.user

Comment: Yes indeed because the the target entity is mapped in the ÈmbeddedIs` and not the Entity, uou should better use option1 and map the `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    private User user;@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Event event;` in the `Attending` Entity, you can check [this tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/08/01/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) it shows a solution too.

Comment: Do i understand, without embeddable class? No man this is what I did at the beginning, it does not work, when try to store an attending it raise the exception that the type are not the same

Comment: @mattobob No I didn't say without the `EmbeddedId`, but to use option1 and just map the `ManyToOne` relations in the Entity itself and not the Embeddable ID, but any way the best approach would be to use `ManyToMany` solution.

Comment: No man many to many is not possible because of the "success" entry which is the main reason because i do use this approach, I need an ID class. Im really lost, can you please show me how i do have to correct my code?

Comment: Have you took a look at the link in my Edit?! It uses a `ManyToMany` with extra columns, you can use `success`property as an extra column.

Comment: I see, this is wonderfull, exactly what I was searching for, thanks